# update winform application when database is updated

Tags: mysql, database, client-server, c++builder, vcl

I have **mysql database** shared between some users. 
I need to update the **client** application (**VCL** forms application : **builder C++**) when a database(mysql) is updated. How can do that?

Comment: Go for it. Or do you have a question?

Comment: i don't know how to do that..!!

Comment: We won't code that completely for you. Ask a specific question where you have a problem with.

Comment: how to notify the client (winform application) by the change in the database? there's there any modules in mysql to do that? is what I need to create a midelwre whose role in listening if there are changes?
I speak here of the concept knowing that my MySQL database and a winform app ..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically update all db clients unless you periodically refresh (reopen) them. But, that is not a good option. Instead, you should use locking mechanisms to check for record concurrency.

See this video for example on how to do this with MS Access database and ADO provider:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENREaK2K9ZQ

Depending on your mysql provider maybe you can do the same.

Comment: what about User defined function Or Mysql proxy?

Comment: That has nothing to do with record concurrency.